# splitting string into numeric and non-numeric part depending on a specific character in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I have this problem that seems awfully trivial, however I can't seem to find a decent way to work around it

I have this data frame that resembles a table with regression outputs:

```
 Variabel       Model 1           Model 2
        A      5.56545* 35.45645343434***
        B 9.334223232**    14.45465464***
        C 64.33232323**         3.798877*
```

Both columns 2 (Model 1) and 3 (Model 2) are string variables. However, I would like round of the numeric part to only have 3 digits. My idea to go about this would be to split up each column, convert the numbers to numeric, round them off to 3 digits and but it back together. To me this seems rather trivial, however i can't seem to find a nice way of working around it, especially one where I can do it for both columns at once.

Could it be done with base R regular expressions, with packages such as stringr and how is it done in the least number of steps.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your plan actually seems like a good idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
round(as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9\\.]", "", "35.45645343434***")),digits = 3)
```

MRE:

```
df <- data.frame(Variable = c("A", "B", "C"),
                 Model1 = x,
                 Model2 = x)
```

As a function:

```
f <- function(x) return(paste0(round(as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9\\.]", "", x)),digits = 3), gsub("[0-9\\.]", "", x)))
```

Use function:

```
cbind(df[, 1, drop=FALSE], apply(df[,-1], 2, f))
```

Returns:

```
  Variable    Model1    Model2
1        A 35.456*** 35.456***
2        B 14.455*** 14.455***
3        C    3.799*    3.799*
```

Comment: Glad I could help. But I'm still hoping someone posts a better solution. I don't think it's  very precise and elegant... there has to be a better way ;)